# Trouble using printf with %s and char*

Tags: c, printf

I'm having some problems with this small piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
struct ether_addr *s, *d;

u_char dir1[] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55};
u_char dir2[] = {0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99,0xaa,0xbb};

s = dir1;
d = dir2;

printf("Together: %s\t%s\n",ether_ntoa(s),ether_ntoa(d));

printf("Apart: %s\t",ether_ntoa(s));
printf("%s",ether_ntoa(d));}
```

The output should be the same but, in fact, it is:

```
Together: 66:77:88:99:aa:bb 66:77:88:99:aa:bb
Apart: 0:11:22:33:44:55 66:77:88:99:aa:bb
```

If I put both dirs in the same line, it prints only one of them. Why is that happening?

Comment: I think you are talking about 2nd `printf()`. Do you use two `%s` when you put in same line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PCAP Destination and Source are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592416/pcap-destination-and-source-are-the-same)

Comment: That duplicate wasn't about _printing_ the results, _per se_, but it explains why the actual buffer returned by multiple calls to `*_ntoa` and `*_aton`  is the same (which has the effect that later calls overwrite the values of earlier calls).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the function is stored in a statically allocated buffer (e.g. in the same buffer each time it is called), so the second call overrides the result of the first one.

> ether_aton() converts the 48-bit Ethernet host address asc from the
>   standard hex-digits-and-colons notation into binary data in network
>   byte order and returns a pointer to it in a **statically allocated**
>   buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite. ether_aton returns NULL
>   if the address is invalid.

If you try and print the pointer returned from the call each time ( `printf( '%p', ether_ntoa(s) );` ), it should be the same...

Consider using `ether_aton_r` which fills a buffer supplied by the caller instead.